# Multiple pattern to parse in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

My log file has more than one pattern including logs in JSON format. I want to parse multiple pattern in grok plugin but it does not seems to be working.

```
'filter {grok {  break_on_match => false 
match =>[ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:LogDate} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} (?<threadName>[^:]+):%{NUMBER:ThreadID} - %{GREEDYDATA:Line}",
           "message","%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:LogDate} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} (?<threadName>[^:]+):%{NUMBER:ThreadID} - %{IP:Clicnet} - - %{GREEDYDATA:Line}"]}
           json {source => "Line"}mutate{remove_field => [ "Line","ThreadID" ]}}'
```

Even though line which is having JSON string parsed successfully, there is grokparsefailure tag.

**2017-01-27 11:54:48 INFO PropertiesReader:33 - {"timestamp":1485518878968,"h":"297268184dde", "l":"INFO", "cN":"org.com.logstash.demo", "mN":"loadProperties", "m":"load property file from /var/tmp/conf"}**

```
{
       "message" => "2017-01-27 11:54:48 INFO PropertiesReader:33 - {\"timestamp\":1485518878968,\"h\":\"297268184dde\", \"l\":\"INFO\", \"cN\":\"org.com.logstash.demo\", \"mN\":\"loadProperties\", \"m\":\"load property file from /var/tmp/conf\"}",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2017-03-20T17:19:16.316Z",
          "type" => "stdin",
          "host" => "ef3b82",
       "LogDate" => "2017-01-27 11:54:48",
      "loglevel" => "INFO",
    "threadName" => "PropertiesReader",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_grokparsefailure"
    ],
     "timestamp" => 1485518878968,
             "h" => "297268184dde",
             "l" => "INFO",
            "cN" => "org.com.logstash.demo",
            "mN" => "loadProperties",
             "m" => "load property file from /var/tmp/conf"
}
```

and 2nd line which do not have JSON is failing completely

**2017-01-20 15:46:16 INFO  RequestLog:60 - 10.252.134.34 - - [20/Jan/2017:15:46:16 +0000] "OPTIONS //127.0.0.0:8080/ HTTP/1.1" 404 237  1**

```
Error parsing json {:source=>"Line", :raw=>["10.252.134.34 - - [20/Jan/2017:15:46:16 +0000] \"OPTIONS //127.0.0.0:8080/ HTTP/1.1\" 404 237  1", "[20/Jan/2017:15:46:16 +0000] \"OPTIONS //127.0.0.0:8080/ HTTP/1.1\" 404 237  1"], :exception=>java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jruby.RubyArray cannot be cast to org.jruby.RubyIO, :level=>:warn}
{
       "message" => "2017-01-20 15:46:16 INFO  RequestLog:60 - 10.252.134.34 - - [20/Jan/2017:15:46:16 +0000] \"OPTIONS //127.0.0.0:8080/ HTTP/1.1\" 404 237  1",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2017-03-20T17:19:51.175Z",
          "type" => "stdin",
          "host" => "ef3b82",
       "LogDate" => [
        [0] "2017-01-20 15:46:16",
        [1] "2017-01-20 15:46:16"
    ],
      "loglevel" => [
        [0] "INFO",
        [1] "INFO"
    ],
    "threadName" => [
        [0] " RequestLog",
        [1] " RequestLog"
    ],
       "Clicnet" => "10.252.134.34",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_jsonparsefailure"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending 5 hours , I managed to find the solution . Used below pattern which parsed both the log lines successfully

```
/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -e 'filter {grok  { match =>{ "message" =>["%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:LogDate} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} (?<threadName>[^:]+):%{NUMBER:ThreadName} - %{IP:Client} - - %{GREEDYDATA:LogMessage}", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:LogDate} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} (?<threadName>[^:]+):%{NUMBER:ThreadID} - %{GREEDYDATA:Line}"]}}  json {source => "Line"} mutate{remove_field => [ "Line","ThreadID" ]}}'
```